# To Ruby on Rails - authenticity_token does not work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ujs

I'm a beginner programmer on Ruby on Rails.
I have a form that adds an object with attached. The file is stored on the cloud from Amazon S3.
Form done through javascript using ujs. In the form of added parameter: `remote: true`. But saving does not occur, and there is an error:
`Missing template cards/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :slim]}.`


Help what to do?


**my form:**

```
  = simple_form_for [@deck, @card], remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f|
    p
      = f.input :original_text, as: :string, label: 'Original text', input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
    p
      = f.input :translated_text, as: :string, label: 'Translated text', input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
    p
      = f.file_field :picture
    p
      = f.button :submit, data: { disable_with: 'Сохраняется...' }, class: "btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block", id: "btn-login"
```

**my new.js.erb:**

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= j render 'cards/new' %>");
```

**my create.js.erb:**

```
$("#modal-window").modal("hide");
$(".cards-index").html('<%= j render 'cards/all', cards: @cards %>');
$("#card_title").val('');
```

Comment: Your form submission hit to cards controller create action. SO by convention you need a create action in cards controller as well as create.js.erb or create.html.erb template to serve the response. So i would suggest you to rename new.create.erb to create.js.erb

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a "create.js.erb".

Comment: What it said! i mean the error now?

Comment: I renamed the file, but the error does not go away.

Comment: Put your error log here: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/Ks8smaAq](http://pastebin.com/Ks8smaAq)

Comment: Where you make create.js.erb? is it in app/views/cards/create.js.erb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! Problem solved.
Added `gem 'remotipart'`
2 Added to the file application.js after `//= require jquery_ujs` string `//= require jquery.remotipart`
3 Added to the form string `authenticity_token: true`